# Cannot access public method in HazelcastSession

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, kotlin, hazelcast

I cannot invoke method in HazelcastSession class. I've obtained object and would like to add attribute via public method. I got this error. 
I'm using Kotlin.
How to solve this?
[image]

The same attempt in Java
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session-hazelcast/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/hazelcast/HazelcastSessionRepository.java#L321 is the definition of `HazelcastSessionRepository`'s inner class `HazelcastSession`

The definition is basically

```
public class HazelcastSessionRepository { 
   final class HazelcastSession {
       public void setAttribute(String attributeName, Object attributeValue) {
```

The inner class (`HazelcastSession`) isn't visible so you can't access what is inside.